# Constrained random numbers always total the constraint with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, width

I'm a JS amateur. I'm looking to randomly set the width and opacity of a bunch of span elements to create an animation effect.

At the moment, the width is set and re-set using `setInterval` every second which is almost working fine...

```
$(function () {
  setInterval(function () {
    // Variables for background colour
    var minFloat = 0.3,
        maxFloat = 0.9,
        randFloat = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxFloat - minFloat + 1)) + minFloat;

    // Set random width
    $('.footerbars span').css('width', Math.random() * 10 + '%');

    // Set random alpha
    $('.footerbars span').css('background-color', 'rgba(58,130,255,' + randFloat + ')');
  }, 1000);
});
```

What I need is:

- the widths of the spans to be each be a different percentage, and for all of those percentages to always total 100%.
- and the background alpha channel to be random for each span

Any help is awesome!! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that all widths and backgrounds will be set to be the same as the random numbers are only generated once. You need something like:

```
$('.footerbars span').each(function(i, e) {
    $(e).css('width', (Math.random() * 10) + '%')
     .css('background-color', 'rgba('58,130,255,' + ((Math.random() * 0.6) + 0.3) +')');
});
```

The problem with this is that the widths may not all add up to 100%. To solve this we need to first generate the set of random numbers, then scale them so they add up to 100, and then apply them to the spans.

```
var numSpans = $('.footerbars span').length;
var widths = [];
var total = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < numSpans; i++) {
    widths[i] = Math.random()+1; // generate a new random width for this span - and make it definitely not zero
    total += widths[i]; // and update the total width so far;
}

// Now we know what the total random number is (something between numSpans and 2*numSpans)
// we can scale these so the sum actually is 100
for(var i = 0; i < numSpans; i++)
    widths[i] = Math.floor(widths[i] * (100 / total));
```

Now `widths[i]` contains the % width of the ith span in .footerbars, so amend the second line of the first bit of code to be:

```
$(e).css('width', widths[i])
```

Full code:

```
var numSpans = $('.footerbars span').length;
var widths = [];
var total = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < numSpans; i++) {
    widths[i] = Math.random()+1; // generate a new random width for this span - and make it definitely not zero
    total += widths[i]; // and update the total width so far;
}

// Now we know what the total random number is (something between numSpans and 2*numSpans)
// we can scale these so the sum actually is 100
for(var i = 0; i < numSpans; i++)
    widths[i] = Math.floor(widths[i] * (100 / total));

$('.footerbars span').each(function(i, e) {
    $(e).css('width', widths[i])
     .css('background-color', 'rgba('58,130,255,' + ((Math.random() * 0.6) + 0.3) +')');
});
```

Comment: your code threw some errors, is this better?
`$('.footerbars span').each( function(i, e) {
  e.css('width', (Math.random() * 10) + '%')
  .css('background-color', 'rgba(58,130,255,' + ((Math.random() * 0.6) + 0.3) + ')');
 });
`

Comment: Could you add the final code as a reference pls. I keep getting errors on every interval. However the bars appear and at different widths and colours which is sweet